Aggregate data in time interval specified by table2 from very large table1
Suppose I have the following 2 tables:
Table1:



date
symbol
time
value




20090101
A
0930
1


20090101
A
0931
2


20090101
A
0932
5


20090101
B
0930
1


20090101
B
0931
6


20090101
B
0932
3


20090102
A
0930
7


20090102
A
0931
9


20090102
A
0932
4


20090102
B
0930
8


20090102
B
0931
2


20090102
B
0932
5



Table2:



date
symbol
starttime
endtime




20090101
A
0930
0931


20090101
B
0931
0932


20090102
A
0932
0932



The goal is to get the sum of the values in the time interval as specified by Table2 from Table1.
In the above example, the output would be:



date
symbol
starttime
endtime
agg_value




20090101
A
0930
0931
3


20090101
B
0931
0932
9


20090102
A
0932
0932
4



Table1's date,symbol,time are unique across rows. Table2's date,symbol can contain duplicates.
A naïve approach would be to do an right outer join on date,symbol for Table1 and Table2, then remove rows where time falls outside of starttime and endtime, then aggregate. The issue is that Table1 is very large (a few billion rows). Table2 can contain 50 million rows.
What would be an optimal query to accomplish this?

you'll get higher quality and more answers if you build an SQL Fiddle on one of the many fiddle sites for this.  It's a lot. to ask for potential answers to build one for you, so they can answer your question.

did you try to use index? like CREATE INDEX idx_table1 ON Table1 (date, symbol, time);
CREATE INDEX idx_table2 ON Table2 (date, symbol, starttime, endtime);

Removed conflicting database product tags. Please add the one back that you actually use.

@darkgbm I'm not sure what you mean by "duplicates" in table2. Is this what you want?: https://dbfiddle.uk/bmfQ2uwj

I'm guessing you want an ASOF join. This is as close as I can get - maybe play around with the WHERE clause a bit:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table1 (
    date Date,
    symbol String,
    starttime UInt32,
    value UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY date;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table2 (
    date Date,
    symbol String,
    starttime UInt32,
    endtime UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY date;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
('20090101','A',0930,1),
('20090101','A',0931,2),
('20090101','A',0932,5),
('20090101','B',0930,1),
('20090101','B',0931,6),
('20090101','B',0932,3),
('20090102','A',0930,7),
('20090102','A',0931,9),
('20090102','A',0932,4),
('20090102','B',0930,8),
('20090102','B',0931,2),
('20090102','B',0932,5);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
('20090101','A',0930,0931),
('20090101','B',0931,0932),
('20090102','A',0932,0932);

SELECT 
    table1.date,
    table1.symbol,
    table1.starttime,
    sum(table1.value)
FROM table1
ASOF JOIN table2
ON table1.symbol = table2.symbol AND table1.date = table2.date AND table1.starttime = table2.starttime AND table1.starttime <= table2.endtime
GROUP BY table1.date, table1.symbol, table1.starttime
ORDER BY 1;

   ┌───────date─┬─symbol─┬─starttime─┬─sum(value)─┐
1. │ 2009-01-01 │ A      │       930 │          1 │
2. │ 2009-01-01 │ B      │       931 │          6 │
3. │ 2009-01-02 │ A      │       932 │          4 │
   └────────────┴────────┴───────────┴────────────┘

